# Tab Bar Controller Storyboard click event on tab bar item

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a Tab Bar Controller in Storyboard, connected with 2 views.
In View 2 (TimelineView) I had set in .h file:

```
@interface Timeline_Overview : UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate>{
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *PostImage;
```

And in .m file:

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{

NSLog(@"test");
if(item.tag==2)
{

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *TimeLine = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Post_Photo_One"];
    [self presentViewController:TimeLine animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    //your code
}
}
```

but this void does not fire :(

Here is a pic from storyboard:
[image: Storyboard]

Can anybody help?

EDIT:

here is my inspection It looks like yours and it does not work :(

[image]

EDIT 2:

Here my Storyboard, I have set the Custom Class to my "Timeline_Overview" from the "Post Image" tab but it does not work :(
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change in the connection inspector the delegate of the `UITabBarController` `delegate` in the `storyboard` to your relevant class, see screenshot:

[image]

and Don't forget to change the identity inspector to your custom tab bar:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your replay: I have edit my question, I have it like in your pic but it does not work :(

Comment: Ok I have but it does not work, if I click on Tab "PostImage" the void does not fire :(

Comment: Ctrl drag. U can also do it by code, but don't forget to change the custom class in the identity inspector to your custom TabBarController

Comment: Ok I hace connected the delegate from the Tab Bar Controller to Tab Bar and is the PostImage Tab I set in custom class my class I postet above is this right?

Comment: Sorry man, I think I didn't explain me clearly. If u don't inherit from UITabBarController and just want to be it's delegate, so leave the custom class as UITabBarController (in the identity inspector), and set by code the delegate like: 'myTabBar.delegate = self;'

Comment: Ok tanks but how I get "myTabBar"?

Comment: If the tab bar is on the appDelegate window so get it from there :)

Comment: OK I forgott to say that the tab bar controller ist not the root view controller and will not handle in the AppDelegate

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboard, do this

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
[tabBar setDelegate:self];
```

Also in AppDelegate, keep `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>`

And then

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   //Write your code here
}
```